# How to lookup from another table with filters applied on loopkup table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a T1 table with column release. And t2 table with columns release and date.

I want to write a dax measure in a way that it return true when I get matching value in t2 table with date filter applied on T2.

Here is my sample data, I wanna get lookupvalue column with "Y" only when I have release in table t2 with date filter April2020 applied to t2.
Also note that the date April 2020 is coming from sclicer so we cannot hardcode it. So we need a calculated measure not calculated column for this.

Can anyone help me in writing a dax measure for this.[image]

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the output that you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks Balaji for offering help, I have updated the sample data. Please help.

Comment: You mean the date filter that is coming from slicer will be current month?

Comment: It can be any month, current month previous month or in between any month... Depends on what users wanna see

Answer (score 0):

Given these tables below that are related to each other by "Release" Column.

[image]

You can create a measure using Relatedtable() and SelectedValue() like below:

Here Release Date is coming from slicer.

[image]

Comment: Balaji I want yes and no on date filter too, like if I select may(date is coming from the sclier), then I should get "no" for all the release. This is getting complicated as none of the releasedate falls in may

Comment: FYI, In the above figure I have named T1 table as Release and T2 Table as ReleaseDate.